# Publishing Website Access is Denied ASP.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I'm having a problem in publishing my website:

```
Transformed Web.config using Web.Debug.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.
Deleting existing files...
Publishing folder /...
Unable to add 'Cottages.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Default.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Global.asax' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'LoggedOut.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Login.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'MasterPage.Master' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'menu.css' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Packages.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Registration.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Rooms.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Rooms.css' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'style.css' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'Web.config' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add 'WebForm1.aspx' to the Web site.  Access is denied (550).<br>
Unable to add folder 'Admin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Admin".<br>
Unable to add folder 'App_Data' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "App_Data".<br>
Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "bin".<br>
Unable to add folder 'css' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "css".<br>
Unable to add folder 'Customer' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Customer".<br>
Unable to add folder 'Employee' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "Employee".<br>
Unable to add folder 'images' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "images".<br>
Unable to add folder 'js' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "js".<br>
========== Build: 8 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a straight-forward permissions issue. Your account (username/password) doesn't have permission to create files and folders on the remote server.

Check with your web-host and ask them to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue just "pops up" when you didn't have an issue with it previously, rebooting always fixes it for me.